# jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name"/>
<input type="text" name="subject" value="" id="subject" />
<input type="text" name="message" value="" id="message" />
```

Can someone tell me the difference if I selected individually the inputs or getting them in one swap.

like

```
var name = jQuery('#name');
var subject= jQuery('#subject');
var message = jQuery('#message');
```

as compared to getting them in one swap

```
jQuery(":input").each(function(){....};)
```

i mean wouldn't jquery have to go back to the document root everytime I call `<input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name"/>` ?

and if from my example I do this

```
<input type="text" name="message" value="" id="message" />
<input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name"/>
```

which means i queried the last input form then queried back the first input form, wouldnt it make the flow slower?

Comment: to format code blocks, select the text and press `ctrl + k`. It just indents them 4 spaces.

Comment: @giddy, thanks got it going, thought i tried here in the comments box, it would only redirect my cursor to the address bar of chrome

Comment: yes comments have limit formatting the _``_ works in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery('#name');` will be faster then `jQuery(":input")`, by a lot.

`jQuery('#name')` will match the selector as an ID and return the item by ID, while `:input` will traverse the entire dom for elements that are of type input.

If you're really worried about selector performance, take a look at http://www.paulirish.com/perf

Comment: thanks for the info and the link, if i had N number of input fields that would mean N number of jquery selectors right? so would the code bloat if i individually add selectors for each id? btw, the inputs are supposed to be validated like checking for empty inputs.. etc

Comment: Add them to an array, var selectors = [$("#name"), $("#message")]; and use $.each on that array.

Answer (score 0):

As Peeter said, using an ID selector will be much faster.

However, you can combine the advantages of both - e.g. use `$('#id-of-your-form :input')`.

Comment: i see, would selecting all inputs through context make it faster? having this form `jQuery( selector, [ context ] )`

Comment: That seems a bit redundant with IDs, it's not like you'll have 2 elements with the same ID, one an input and another a div. Although yes, you can check if the ID is an input with that method.

Comment: If your inputs have IDs, use those. If they don't, use context, but look through Paul Irish's video to use context properly.

Comment: @peeter if i had N number of inputs then i would have to write individual selectors for each input id's, then how can i strike a balance between speed and having to write N number of selectors?

Answer (score 0):

As metioned above by @ThiefMaster you can combine by using `$('#id-of-your-form :input')` but it is also has perfomace issue because jQuery's Sizzle selector engine is parsing selector from right to left.

To get more perfomace you can use the following way

```
$(':input', $('#id-of-your-form').get(0))
```

This will lead to selector search in context of concrete DOM element.
Also note, what it is not the same as

```
$(':input', $('#id-of-your-form'))
```

This will be internally "refactored" like

```
$('#id-of-your-form :input')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an id selector (like `#name`), then it can use the `document.getElementById` method, which is very efficient. Using a selector like `:input` will at least require several calls to `getElementsByTagName`, and looping through all the found elements to check what they really are. Some selectors, like a class selector, are even more expensive as it requires to loop through all elements in the page to look for the elements that match.

If you select elements by id, then it doesn't matter which order you do that. jQuery evaluates each selector separately, it doesn't expect you to query the elements in any specific order.

You can use a selector like `#name,#subject,#message` to get all three elements in the same jQuery collection, which is more efficient if you want to use the same method on them.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to speed up your query than jQuery like this:

```
<div id="inputs">
<input type="text" id="message" />
<input type="text" id="name" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

1. First select the element that is
   parent..

   ```
   var inputsContainer = $("#inputs");
   ```
2. Select input element FROM parent..
   (will only do query from container not the whole the DOM-object)

   ```
   var message = $("#message", inputsContainer);
   var name = $("#name", inputsContainer);
   ```

Comment: If "context" argument is jQuery object it will not give perfomace gain. You need to pass concrete DOM element.

Comment: You mean like this? 
var inputsContainer = $("#inputs")[0]; ?

Comment: Yes. Just imagine if you jQuery object, which you are passing as context, is containing more than one element? Which one to choose? Well, jQuery just rewrites the main selector to complete such search.